# Rails 4 Login/Sign up using devise during form submission authenticity token error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise, authenticity-token

I have a Project model. There's one-to-many association with the Project model and the Devise User model. I want the users to perform ajax login using Devise before submitting the Projects form data.

The Ajax login works fine. But, after the login when I try and submit the Projects form I get an authenticity token error. I understand that this is due to the change of session token change. But I wonder if there's any way to maintain this kind of user flow?

Comment: Show me the form, it's relevant

Comment: Hi Alain,
I think I fixed the user flow with the following solution that basically required some jQuery code.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34824860/3663937

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed it with some simple jQuery code. I basically needed to replace the existing authenticity token on the parent form with the new one after sign in. Previously had enabled the Devise session method to respond to js format and had the file `/devise/sessions/create.js.erb`.

On the same file I had to append the following jQuery code to replace the existing authenticity token on the form with the new one generated after logging in.

```
$("input[name='authenticity_token'").val("<%= form_authenticity_token %>");
```

Comment: A bit hacky but should work well - do you have any reason why you're not refreshing the page after a successful login?

Comment: Thanks, Rich.
The user flow is:
* Click on 'New Project'
* Fill up the form with specifications
* Authentication
   ** If you already have an account login with username and password
   ** Otherwise, you fill up the sign up form and register
* Submit the form and


The parent form is is ajax to avoid page refresh. The sign up process was quite straight forward with the Project model accepting nested attributes.

I needed the sign in to take place on the fly before submitting the form. Although the solution is a bit hacky, it did the trick.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Ah okay, so your login is meant to interject into an already defined flow? Nice, I like it :) I've not got massive experience with it... I would say it's kind of weak to just replace the auth token, but that's only my opinion. Perhaps replacing the form from the server or something?